# The sandbox for Neo4J not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: neo4j, internet-explorer-11, sandbox

I'm currently working on an organization that prevents me from installing other browsers so I have to work on IE 11. Is there any limitation to Neo4J's Sandbox or is it generally not working right now?

For those with access to other browsers here's the link:

https://neo4j.com/sandbox-v2/

Thank you for your replies

Comment: Things are currently working. A quick check shows that Firefox and Chrome are opening a login window (when you click "Start Now"), IE throws a lot of errors and does not ...

Comment: Thank you. I unfortunately could not check myself as in office I have no access to any browser other than Internet Explorer so I was not sure whether it was an IE only issue. I'll close this question.

Comment: are you able to run portable firefox - https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable - from a usb flash drive?

Comment: I'm not allowed to plug a flash drive, let alone use non allowed software from that flash drive.. Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not working on IE 11.0!
Thanks to Tom Geudens and Dave Bennett for your help.